# SAS: keeping a variable in a macro that exist only in one table

Tags: macros, sas

In the following macro, I want to keep column that only exist in table2 but not table1. Is there a way to have the loop disregard the variable in the keep statement when it is not present in the table but keep it when it is in the table?

> MWE

```
data table1;
    format id date $9.;
    input id date;
    datalines;
    1 12may2016
    2 13may2016
    ;
run;

data table2;
    format id date $9.;
    input id date ser;
    datalines;
    1 12may2016 123456789
    2 13may2016 012345678
    ;
run;

data names;
    format name $6.;
    input name;
    datalines;
    table1
    table2
    ;
run;

data _null_;
   set names nobs = n;
   call symput ('cnt', n);
run;

%macro test;
%do i = 1 %to &cnt;
    data first;
        set names (obs = 1);
    run;
    data _null_;
        set first;
        call symput ('name', trim(name));
    run;
    data run_&name;
        set &name (keep = id date ser);
    run;
    data names;
        set names (firstobs = 2);
    run;
%end;
%mend test;

%test;
```

> ERROR: The variable ser in the DROP, KEEP, or RENAME list has never been referenced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just change the setting of the `DKRICOND` or `DKROCOND` option?

> Syntax
>
> DKRICOND=ERROR | WARN | WARNING | NOWARN | NOWARNING
>
> Syntax Description
>
> ERROR
>
> sets the error flag and writes an error message to the SAS log when a variable is missing from an input data set during the processing of a DROP=, KEEP=, or RENAME= data set option.
>
> WARN | WARNING
>
> writes a warning message to the SAS log when a variable is missing from an input data set during the processing of a DROP=, KEEP=, or RENAME= data set option.
>
> NOWARN | NOWARNING
>
> does not write a warning message to the SAS log when a variable is missing from an input data set during the processing of a DROP=, KEEP=, or RENAME= data set option.

Comment: The first loop through the macro doesn't execute due to the warning. Suppressing the warning, I don't believe will help.

Comment: If you set `options dkricond=nowarn` before the data step with the dataset option `KEEP=ser` then SAS will run the step and it will not generate an error or even a warning.  But the variable will not be created unless there is some other code, such as a `LENGTH` statement, to make it.

Comment: Okay, I see that worked. Is this something I would turn back on after the datastep in question? If so, would it be `options dkricond = error`?

Comment: Yes. Or better save the current setting to a macro.  `%let save=%sysfunc(getoption(dkricond)); option dkricond=nowarn;....;options dkricond=&save;`